# how to peek at a single char in a non-buffered reader in java

Tags: java, buffer, peek

I'm writing a program that takes a Reader and parses input from that reader. I cannot use a BufferedReader, but I would like to implement a peek method that looks at the current char in the reader, without actually calling read() on that character. Is there an easier/better way to do this than converting it to a character array or a string and looking at the character?  I would love to use the mark() method but unfortunately that only works on a buffered reader.

Comment: Why not BufferedReader? The reason for not using one may affect what, if any, solutions are available.

Comment: What about `PushbackInputStream`?

Comment: I'm writing this to a spec that dictates that we cannot use buffered readers. doesn't PushbackInputStream also require the use of a buffered reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural solution is to use `PushBackReader` which provides `unread` methods that can be used to implement `peek`.  (You can work out the details!)

But it is not entirely clear if this is allowed.  It depends whether you are forbidden from using `BufferedReader` or "a buffered `Reader`".  In the latter case, `PushBackReader` is arguably a buffered `Reader`.

If you have to implement this without using an existing buffered `Reader` class, then how you should approach this depends on how much lookahead is needed:

- If you need just one character lookahead (e.g. just `peek`) then you can implement this using an `int` to represent the lookahead and a `boolean` to say if it is currently valid.
- If you need multiple characters lookahead, you need an array (or list), and so on.

---

For the record, the `mark()` and `reset()` methods are actually in the `Reader` API.  The problem is that not all `Reader` classes are able to implement these methods ... due to limitations of the underlying streams ... at the operating system level.

Comment: The spec is slightly ambiguous and states that the reader cannot be buffered. In this case I think that a pushback reader might be applicable because the reader itself isn't buffered, but contains a one character pushback buffer. It also does not support the mark operation, which is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @user1601687 - interpreting your spec is really between you and whoever wrote it.  I'm guessing it is your lecturer.  But in that case, you would probably be better off considering what he/she intends you to do.  And I'd surmise that he/she *intends* you to implement all of the peek / pushback code yourself ... as a programming exercise.  I'm pretty sure they *don't* intend you to use `PushBackReader` ... and if you use it, you risk getting down-marked.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own class with peek method based on java.io.PushBackReader.